# Parsing a JSON string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I have a string that I want to parse in Ruby:

```
string = '{"desc":{"someKey":"someValue","anotherKey":"value"},"main_item":{"stats":{"a":8,"b":12,"c":10}}}'
```

Is there an easy way to extract the data?

Comment: _JSON is directly supported in Ruby, and has been since at least Ruby v1.9.3, so there is no need to install a gem unless you're using something older. Simply use `require 'json'` in your code._

Answer (score 642, accepted):

This looks like [JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)](http://www.json.org). You can parse JSON that resides in some variable, e.g. `json_string`, like so:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse(json_string)
```

If you’re using an older Ruby, you may need to install the [json gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/json).

---

There are also other implementations of JSON for Ruby that may fit some use-cases better:

- [YAJL C Bindings for Ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/yajl-ruby)
- [JSON::Stream](https://rubygems.org/gems/json-stream)

Comment: Also you can sets the option symbolize_names to true, in order to get keys as symbols. Exemple: `JSON.parse(string, symbolize_names: true) #=> {key: :value}`

Comment: _JSON is directly supported in Ruby, and has been since at least Ruby v1.9.3, so there is no need to install a gem unless you're using something older. Simply use `require 'json'` in your code._

Answer (score 239):

Just to extend the answers a bit with what to do with the parsed object:

```
# JSON Parsing example
require "rubygems" # don't need this if you're Ruby v1.9.3 or higher
require "json"

string = '{"desc":{"someKey":"someValue","anotherKey":"value"},"main_item":{"stats":{"a":8,"b":12,"c":10}}}'
parsed = JSON.parse(string) # returns a hash

p parsed["desc"]["someKey"]
p parsed["main_item"]["stats"]["a"]

# Read JSON from a file, iterate over objects
file = open("shops.json")
json = file.read

parsed = JSON.parse(json)

parsed["shop"].each do |shop|
  p shop["id"]
end
```

Comment: Important note: `'{ "a": "bob" }'` is valid. `"{ 'a': 'bob' }"` is not.

Comment: @LinusAn because JSON requires double quotes around strings.
See string in the JSON definition ( http://www.json.org/ ): "A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes."

Comment: In many cases you want to wrap `JSON.parse` within a rescue block for `JSON::ParserError`.

Comment: `JSON.parse("[#{value}]")[0]` to avoid the error `A JSON text must at least contain two octets!`

Comment: Can you make your answer complete by including a sample example data from shops.json?

Answer (score 42):

As of Ruby v1.9.3 you don't need to install any Gems in order to parse JSON, simply use `require 'json'`:

```
require 'json'

json = JSON.parse '{"foo":"bar", "ping":"pong"}'
puts json['foo'] # prints "bar"
```

See [JSON](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) at Ruby-Doc.

Answer (score 18):

It looks like a JSON string.  You can use one of many JSON libraries and it's as simple as doing:

```
JSON.parse(string)
```

Answer (score 10):

Don't see any answers here that mention parsing directly to an object other than a Hash, but it is possible using the poorly-documented object_class option(see https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html):

```
JSON.parse('{"foo":{"bar": 2}}', object_class: OpenStruct).foo.bar
=> 2
```

The better way to read that option is "The ruby class that a json object turns into", which explains why it defaults to Hash. Likewise, there is an array_class option for json arrays.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit late but I ran into something interesting that seems important to contribute.

I accidentally wrote this code, and it seems to work:

```
require 'yaml'
CONFIG_FILE = ENV['CONFIG_FILE'] # path to a JSON config file 
configs = YAML.load_file("#{CONFIG_FILE}")
puts configs['desc']['someKey']
```

I was surprised to see it works since I am using the YAML library, but it works.

The reason why it is important is that `yaml` comes built-in with Ruby so there's no gem install.

I am using versions 1.8.x and 1.9.x - so the `json` library is not built in, but it is in version 2.x.

So technically - this is the easiest way to extract the data in version lower than 2.0.

Comment: Yes, JSON is actually parsed by the Psych code, which also parses YAML in Ruby. And JSON parsing was introduced in [Ruby v1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html).

Comment: The reason this works is that semantically (most) JSON is valid YAML (particularly YAML 1.2)

Comment: I get "undefined method `load_file' for JSON:Module" on ruby 2.3.8

Answer (score 4):

I suggest Oj as it is waaaaaay faster than the standard JSON library.

https://github.com/ohler55/oj

([see performance comparisons here](https://github.com/ohler55/oj#performance-comparisons))

Answer (score 3):

If you want to deserialise to your own class instead of OpenStruct it doesn't take a lot of work to make the following possible:

```rb
require 'json'
# result is an instance of MyClass
result = JSON.parse(some_json_string, object_class: MyClass)
```

All you have to do is to provide a zero-argument constructor and implement the `#[]=` method which `JSON.parse` will call. If you don't want to expose it, it's sufficient to let it be private:

```rb
class MyClass
  attr_reader :a, :b

  private

  def []=(key, value)
    case key
    when 'a' then @a = value
    when 'b' then @b = value
    end
  end
end
```

Trying it out in irb:

```
> JSON.parse('{"a":1, "b":2}', object_class: MyClass)
=> #<MyClass:0x00007fe00913ae98 @a=1, @b=2>
```

A caveat with this approach is that it only works for flat structures, because the `object_class` argument really tells the parser what class it should use to deserialise JSON objects in the string instead of `Hash` (see the similar argument `array_class` for the analogous operation for JSON arrays). For nested structures this will mean you will use the same class to represent all layers:

```
> JSON.parse('{"a":1, "b":{ "a": 32 }}', object_class: MyClass)
=> #<MyClass:0x00007fb5110b2b38 @a=1, @b=#<MyClass:0x00007fb5110b2908 @a=32>>
```