# Javascript or Ruby. Reformat a JSON object

Tags: javascript, ruby, json

I need to turn this JSON object:

```
[
    [
        "email@email.com"
    ],
    [
        "email2@email.com"
    ],
    [
        "email3@email.com"
    ],
    [
        "email4@email.com"
    ]
]
```

Into this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "email": "email@email.com"
        },
        {
            "email": "email2@email.com"
        },
        {
            "email": "email3@email.com"
        },
        {
            "email": "email4@email.com"
        }
] }
```

How is this done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing a JSON string in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's really just an array of arrays, but that's besides the point. Just loop through the array of arrays and push the relevant data onto the new array in your object:

```
var my_new_object = {};
my_new_object['data'] = [];

for (var i = 0; i < your_array.length; i++) {
  my_new_object.data.push({"email": your_array[i][0]});
}
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4jLX/).

Comment: You're close, but I think you need: your_array[i][0]

Comment: Its very close. The [] around the email address should not be there. How can I remove it? http://pastie.org/1812997.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
var original = [
[
    "email@email.com"
],
[
    "email2@email.com"
],
[
    "email3@email.com"
],
[
    "email4@email.com"
]
];

var output = {};
output.data = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<original.length;i++){
    var o = new Object();
    o.email = original[i][0];
    output.data.push(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can test it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/v3fnk/

```
var data=[["email@email.com"],["email2@email.com"],["email3@email.com"],["email4@email.com"]];

for (var i in data) {
    for (var x in data[i]) {
        $("#info").append(data[i][x] + '<br/>');
    }

}
```