# Parsing string coming from API

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I have a string like this coming from an API:

```
 "{\"region\":{\"span\":{\"latitude_delta\":0.11197800000000058,\"longitude_delta\":0.10020299999999338},.....
```

What should I do in order to be able to access `my_returned_object.region`? Right now it's just a string, I don't know how to convert it to another object type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a string containing encoded [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

You need to [install and use a JSON parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby) to turn it into a hash.

First, install the gem:

```
gem install json
```

Then use it:

```
require 'json'

data = JSON.parse("{\"region\":{\"span\":{\"latitude_delta\":0.11197800000000058,\"longitude_delta\":0.10020299999999338}}}")

puts data["region"]
```

Comment: @KulbirSaini The sample posted by the OP is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a JSON encoded object. You could try

```
require 'json'
my_hash = JSON.load(my_returned_object).symbolize_keys
puts my_hash[:region]
```

json is part of Ruby 1.9, if you use 1.8 (or another Ruby implementation) you might need to install the json gem using gem install json.