# Constructing Ruby's regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I need some guidance on how to do the following..
Let say I have this string below 
s= {"name":testName,"age":20}

how should I construct my regular expression in ruby, such that I am able to get "testName"
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this JSON? It looks like JSON but it lacks quotation marks on *testName* so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jason about using JSON, but if you really can't...

```
1.9.3p194 > s= '{"name":testName,"age":20}'
 => "{\"name\":testName,\"age\":20}" 
1.9.3p194 > s =~ /"name":(.*?)(,"|})/
 => 1 
1.9.3p194 > puts $1
testName
```

Note that this is evil and wrong and will probably hurt little kittens... use JSON to save the kittens.

Answer (score 2):

The data you have is a JSON string. You should not parse it with a regular expression, but parse it into an object and then access the `name` property.

I am not a Ruby dev, but you can do so if you have the [JSON gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby).