# How to convert a serialized array string to an array?

Tags: ruby

I have this string :

```
temp = "["minutes", "hours"]"
```

If I do this:

```
temp[1..-2].split(", ")
```

I get an array of 2 elements like this:

```
[0] = ""minutes""
[1] = ""hours""
```

How can I avoid to have double quotes?

Comment: That looks like it came from JSON. Perhaps you ought to use a JSON parser?

Comment: `require 'json'`  and `JSON.parse temp`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby

Comment: It's actually a serialized array I stored as string in a sql hash, so I get the first string. Indeed it looks like JSON but I'd rather not user a JSON gem for this piece of code.

Comment: That is not a valid Ruby string.

Comment: I used https://github.com/ohler55/oj since I already had the dependency in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more:

```
the_string.scan(/\"(\w+)\"/).flatten
 => ["minutes", "hours"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the JSON parser :

```
JSON.parse(your_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
temp.gsub("\"", "")[1..-2].split(", ")
```

Or, once you have the array with double quotes on each element:

```
temp.map{|e| e.squeeze("̣\"")}
```