# Middleman JSON local data

Tags: json, local, middleman

I am pretty new to Middleman and Ruby so I apology in advance...

I'm trying to read via "Middleman local data" some JSON files I have in my data folder and then save the result into a environment variable, so I can eventually pass it to my JS files. Something like this:

```
- data.test.each do |t|
    - set :json_data, t
```

This is actually reading my /data/test.json file and saving it into json_data variable. However, it's not in JSON format. It's just a string concatenation of all my nodes.
My guess is I need to decode the JSON info before saving it into the variable. Something like?

```
- data.test.each do |t|
    - set :json_data, ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(t)
```

But this is not working either. 
I tried to install a json gem but it did work.

Any clue of what I may be missing?

Answer (score 2):

ActiveSupport is a Rails module which you don't get with Middleman.  Assuming you've installed the JSON gem, you can do something like this:

```
string = File.read('/path/to/json/file.json')

json = JSON.parse(string)

json.each do |node|
  # do your stuff here
```

More here: [Parsing a JSON string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby)

Comment: Wow...I just saw this.
I actually ended up doing something very similiar!

Sorry and thank you (guess better late than never)