# How to read text with javascript as json or ruby object

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I have text with javascript code like this:

```
var data = {"name": "lorem ipsum", "brand": "ipsum", "attr": { "sizes": [{"name": "big", "value": "1"}, {"name": "small", "value": "2"}], "height":[{"name": "large", "value": "1"}], "url": "http://...", "desc": "lorem ipsum"}
```

How can I read it as json or some ruby object? I need import these datas to db. This text is return of API, which I get with Ruby(RoR) code.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5410713/326543) help?

Comment: You might want to investigate Ruby's JSON module:  http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html  Just be careful what options you use:  parsing untrusted input has led to severe security issues.

Comment: Thank you, I deleted "var data = " and then I parsed with json, thank you