# Stuck with HTTP GET authentication in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, authentication

I am trying to write short script to do HTTP authentication using GET request

This makes GET request.

```
    def try_login(u, p)
      path1 = '/index.php'
      path2 = '?uuser=#{myuser}&ppass=#{mypass}'
      r = send_request_raw({
        'URI' => "#{path1}#{path2}",
        'method' => 'GET'
      })
    ...continued...
```

But this code does not work because error says:

> undefined local variable or method `myuser'

--> Basically I am trying to send one (1) GET request with login parameters, and the app responds with a specific data. And I do not know how to put placeholders for `user` and `pass` in this GET request.

...

Next, I am checking the HTTP response. Response comes in as JSON mime like this:

Success response

```
{"param1":1,"param2"="Auth Success","menu":0,"userdesc":"My User","user":"uuser","pass":"ppass","check":"success"}
```

Fail response

```
{"param1":-1,"param2"="Auth Fail","check":"fail"}
```

--> How can I check the response body for this kind of data.

I have been trying all day now, but stuck totally. Please advice.

Edit: 
I do not understand why some one down voted this question saying little to no research on my part. Until before yesterday morning, I had absolutely zero idea about ruby code & working with it. And then I spent numerous hours looking at many different examples, making my script and testing it out. When it still didn't work, I asked my question here. Please, if you still want to down vote, do it but please, at least share some pointers to solve this as well.

Comment: why can't you just say if (r['param2'] == 'Auth Fail')... ? -- assuming you've parsed the json..

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the json? Also, that's not http authentication.

Comment: Yes, I have 2 questions. First is how to send a GET request with username and password placeholders, so that I can eventually loop through user, pass values. Second is once I receive the json response, how can I parse to find the pass/fail keyword.

Comment: Ask ONE question at a time, not multiple questions, unless they are closely related. Your two are not closely related.

Comment: @theTinMan both are related subparts of one exercise. I am trying to do the task with 1 GET request only which I know returns a specific content type response. Hence I put both sections here.

Comment: I really hope that those GET requests are over an HTTPS connection.  Also, sending back the password in a JSON response is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: @rtcherry the GET request with this app goes to port 8443. http://ip:8443/login.php?user=&pass=

Answer (score 0):

```
def try_login(u, p)
  path1 = '/index.php'
  path2 = '?uuser=#{myuser}&ppass=#{mypass}'
  r = send_request_raw({
    'URI' => "#{path1}#{path2}",
    'method' => 'GET'
  })
...continued...
```

Should be:

```
def try_login(u, p)
  path1 = '/index.php'
  path2 = "?uuser=#{u}&ppass=#{p}"
  r = send_request_raw({
    'URI' => "#{path1}#{path2}",
    'method' => 'GET'
  })
...continued...
```

For parsing JSON in Ruby, I would recommend you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5410713/2355083) answer to another question.

**Edit**: The reason `try_login(u, p)` isn't working as you would expect is because Ruby does not do string interpolation for single quoted (`'`) strings.  Additionally, `myuser` and `mypass` do not appear to be the correct variables.

Comment: Thanks for replying @rtcherry. But I do not follow. Do you mean, when I do a 'URI' => "#{path1}#{path2}", this action is not supported by Ruby? If this is the case, how can I achieve this any other way...?

Comment: Also, the variables, myuser and mypass are just shown for clarity here. The actual code has u & p like you pointed out.. Thanx!

Comment: @Sunshine Lets say `u = 'test_user'` and `p = 'test_password'`.  `'?uuser=#{u}&ppass=#{p}'` will give you the string `?uuser=#{u}&ppass=#{p}`, but `"?uuser=#{u}&ppass=#{p}"` will give you the string `?uuser=test_user&ppass=test_password`.