# Parsing JSON found at the end of HTML document

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to pull the highlights from Readmill, but it seems like the easiest way to get them is to use search instead of the API.

at the end of

> https://readmill.com/search?q=%22the+great+gatsby%22+%22Francis+Scott+Fitzgerald%22&filter=highlight

You find

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="page-template-data">
  App.templateData.filter = 'highlight';
App.templateData.searchResult =
```

and then a bunch of JSON. Is there a handy Rails friendly way of parsing this JSON?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're helped out by the face that the search result is all on one line. Now, if they ever change ANYTHING about this, this will break. But this will use text manipulation to extract this out into a JSON array for you:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

json = {}
open('https://readmill.com/search?q=the+great+gatsby&filter=highlight').each do |line|
  if line =~ /App.templateData.searchResult/
    json = JSON.parse line.sub('App.templateData.searchResult = ','').strip.to_s[0..-2]
    break
  end
end

puts json.map{|j| j["title"] }
 => “Gatsby?” demanded Daisy. “What Gatsby?”
    ...
```