# how to implement api in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2

In my rails application i want to use lite coins api calls. please let me know how to use this api in rails application.

I have implemented for bit coins i got this code:

from this i am getting the bit coins current value:

```
 <%  response = HTTParty.get("http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCINR/money/ticker") %> 
    <% high = response["data"]["high"]["value"] %>
    <%  low = response["data"]["low"]["value"] %>
    <%  avg = response["data"]["avg"]["value"] %>
```

If anyone knows similar to this please help me out finding the current value of lite coins.

Comment: you can create a function in lib file something:
def get_coins
  response = HTTParty.get("http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCINR/money/ticker")
response
end
let me know if not works ?

Comment: i have implemented this for bit coins.the above code is for bitcoins and this is working fine. actually i need similar code for litecoins.

Comment: So I think you must look into this http://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api , But I'm not sure.

Comment: I need for litecoins. If you have any idea about litecoins please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse JSON. Look into this: [Parsing a JSON string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby)

Basically you get a hash of values and can use it as you like.

Your code won't work since you miss a parser.