# Extract specific field from JSON nested hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-crawler

I am thinking of writing a web application that crawls an API and returns this information in JSON form.

However, I am only after one number, then current price (in this sample, "227"). How can I access that in Ruby?  I have no clue where to begin. I've never dealt with text like this.

For discussion's sake, suppose I save this output into instance variable `@information`

```
{
    "item": {
        "icon": "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4332_obj_sprite.gif?id=4798",
        "icon_large": "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4332_obj_big.gif?id=4798",
        "id": 4798,
        "type": "Ammo",
        "typeIcon": "http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo",
        "name": "Adamant brutal",
        "description": "Blunt adamantite arrow...ouch",
        "current": {
            "trend": "neutral",
            "price": 227
        },
        "today": {
            "trend": "neutral",
            "price": 0
        },
        "day30": {
            "trend": "positive",
            "change": "+1.0%"
        },
        "day90": {
            "trend": "positive",
            "change": "+1.0%"
        },
        "day180": {
            "trend": "positive",
            "change": "+2.0%"
        },
        "members": "true"
    }
}
```

Comment: You only want to find where "227" appears? Or you want to find all "price" occurrences? Or do you want to access the "current price"?

Comment: Current price. Uandl solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First follow this post to parse this **JSON** in to **Hash**
[Parsing a JSON string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby)

say the parsed hash name is my_hash then the following should give you price

```
my_hash['item']['current']['price']
```

**Edit:**

As you said you want to save it in `@information`

```
@information = my_hash['item']['current']['price']
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you can use [hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) it gives your json into readable structural code

Install Hashie

`gem install hashie`

then in your code all that json take in a variable my_json

`myhash = Hashie::Mash.new(my_json)`

`@information = my_hash.item.current.price`

Tips:-
if your json is dynamic and it may respond some other structural element so you can maintain exceptional code

`@information = my_hash.item.try(:current).try(:price)`