# Sass: How can I decode JSON file directly into a Sass variable?

Tags: css, json, web, sass

Is possible decode a JSON file with Node-Sass?

Ex:

```
@import "../data/data.json";
```

I need iterate this data directly into a variable

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: `@import "../data/data.json";` is only supposed to be used to import a sass file. why would it magically decode json? try using ruby to decode the json for you then import it into sass.

Comment: @agconti yeahh, my example is a little crazy, but how decoded with ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how you would do it but here is a great example on how to add custom ruby functions to sass:

https://gist.github.com/chriseppstein/1561650

And heres one on how to parse json:

[Parsing a JSON string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby)

Maybe after putting them together you could do something like this?

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def json(Sass::Script::String)
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'json'
    JSON.parse(string)
  end
end
```

Add it to the end of your `config.rb` file, and make sure you have json ruby gem installed:

```
gem install json
```

and run:

```
compass compile --force
```

to get it all to work.

`*` this is obviously untested and doesn't work, but it might help you get where you need to go.

Comment: @Raul you need to compile Sass with Grunt and require your custom ruby script with `require:’/path/to/script.rb’` (relatively to your project’s root)

Answer (score 13):

[sass-json-vars](https://github.com/vigetlabs/sass-json-vars) is an excellent gem, but won't work with `node-sass` (which is a requirement of the original question).

Instead, try [node-sass-json-importer](https://github.com/Updater/node-sass-json-importer), which is essentially the same thing, only re-worked to fit into `node-sass`'s importer api.

Answer (score 10):

There's a gem called **[Sass JSON Vars](https://github.com/vigetlabs/sass-json-vars)** that does exactly what you want.

You can install the gem with the following command line code:

```
gem install sass-json-vars
```

---

### HOW TO USE Sass JSON Vars

**For projects using Sass >= 3.3**

Place variables in a JSON file:

```
// variables.json
{
    "font-sans": "Helvetica, sans-serif",
    "colors": {
        "red": "#c33"
    }
}
```

Import the file in Sass to expose variable names:

```
@import "variables.json"

body {
    color: map-get($colors, red);
    font: $font-sans;
}
```

Require sass-json-vars when compiling:

```
sass style.scss -r sass-json-vars
```

---

**For projects using Sass <= 3.2**

Place variables in a JSON file:

```
// variables.json
{
    "font-sans": "Helvetica, sans-serif",
    "colors-red": "#c33"
}
```

Import the file in Sass to expose variable names:

```
@import "variables.json"

body {
    color: $colors-red;
    font: $font-sans;
}
```

Require sass-json-vars when compiling:

```
sass style.scss -r sass-json-vars
```

---

**More info :**

- [The project's Github page](https://github.com/vigetlabs/sass-json-vars)
- [Sharing Data Between Sass and JavaScript with JSON](http://viget.com/extend/sharing-data-between-sass-and-javascript-with-json)

Comment: How I implement this when using Compass?

Comment: @Batandwa : AFAIK, all you need to consider, is which version of Sass you're using. It shouldn't make a difference whether or not you're using Compass. If the procedure described doesn't work for you, you might want to contact the dev team @ http://viget.com/ or open an issue @ https://github.com/vigetlabs/sass-json-vars/issues.

Comment: Doesn't parse `.` and `:` (so you can't include urls or references to other assets). Breaks on something like `{ "img": "https://cloudfront.com/foo/bar.jpg" }`

Comment: @Daniel_L : You should log that as an issue @ https://github.com/vigetlabs/sass-json-vars/issues

Comment: @JohnSlegers this issue has been open since November haha... https://github.com/vigetlabs/sass-json-vars/issues/23