# Access attributes for a databag using chef

Tags: chef-infra, databags

I have a ruby script that references a databag's attributes. I would like to know if there is a way to reference databag attributes inside of a databag. Then, when i reference the databag attribute inside of my script, it would point me to another databag's attribute.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5410682/122139.  Search Internet on `chef json parser` for more of the same.

Comment: I apologize if I did a bad job renaming your post.  Maybe it needs to specify you are using one databag to reference another.  However I think the essential question is about parsing databag content, so maybe the title I gave is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Data bags are just [JSON](http://www.json.org/). They are not a programming language, so this is not possible.