# Access Elements in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, http

i want to access elements in JSON.

My JSON looks like:

```
{
"@odata.context":
"https://www.ccyyxxxyyy5......com.ne.de/odata/$metadata#Product(Id,Name)
/$entity","Id":1,"Name":"Build your own computer"
 }
```

I want only access "Id" and "Name". How can I do that? Can anybode make me an example?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you [read the documentation on JSON](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)? Have you read any [other StackoverFlow answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34295262/1954610) on how to parse JSON? Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice on what to do before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you json is saved in `my_json`, it is very much similar to hash, just that the keys are stringified. `my_json[key]` is the syntax to get the value of key. In your case:

```
my_json['Id']
#=> 1
```

---

You seem to be working with JSON array, then:

```
names = my_json.map { |j| j['Name'] }
#=> ["Build your own computer", ..]
```

---

Based on json body provided:

```
data_array = data['value']
name_at_0 = data_array[0]['Name']
name_at_1 = data_array[1]['Name']
#=> etc...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. How can I access the elements when I have more than one element with the same keys?

Comment: same multiple keys within the same hash is a malformed json, it should not be the case as keys are identifiers and it has to be unique.

Comment: share your example json you want to traverse.

Comment: data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(res.body)
@title = data[1]["Name"]

Comment: this is my last version of test

Comment: i get only blank screen

Comment: why `data[1]`? if you have json array, check my updated answer. If it doesn't work, share output of `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(res.body)` or `data`.

Comment: the output of data: {"@odata.context"=>"https://cxcxcxcxssss.ne.com.c.de/odata/$metadata#Product", "value" =>[{"ProductTypeId" =>5, "Id" => 1, "Name"=>"Test"},{"ProductTypeId" =>5, "Id" => 2, "Name"=>"Test2"}, and so on

Comment: i want access the elements seperately like data[0]["Name"]

Comment: You should have provided that earlier. Nevamind, check my edit and it should work now. Please provide full details when you post your next question henceforth and also go through the links provided in the comments above.