# How I can parse JSON file by pure Ruby code without gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I Have tried many ways and googled but everywhere i getting same way out, use json gem to parse a JSON file.

```
JSON.parse(string)
```

And couple of links are also using same
[stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby)

I wanted to achieve it by pure Ruby code without using any gem or rails help.

Comment: Please have a look on a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11430924/5922155)

Comment: @asmitakalena I have already attached a link like that though thanks for prompt reply

Answer (score 23):

`JSON` is in the stdlib, so using `JSON.parse` is pure ruby.

```
require "json"
json_from_file = File.read("myfile.json")
hash = JSON.parse(json_from_file)
```

or just `JSON.parse("{}")`

If you're looking to write your own JSON parser (good luck), but just keep in mind that it's just a string when read from a file. So, start by reading it in from your file

```
File.open("myfile.json") do |f|
  str = f.gets
  # start parsing
end
```

At this point you'll need to tokenize what you read, and start picking apart each bit. Read up on the json spec.

Comment: Thanks But I am newbie can you please help to write this. And +1 from side for your answer

Comment: Sorry, I actually can't. Writing a json parser shouldn't be done by a newbie because it's SUPER difficult. Just use the stdlib JSON. `require "json"` and then `JSON.parse(json_string)`.

Comment: I updated my example on how to parse json from a file using the standard library. Like I said, using JSON.parse is pure ruby, not an external gem.

Comment: He meant as in: not having to import anything.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is part of the core Ruby library (as of 1.9.3 I believe).  You just have to require it in your ruby application/file

```
require 'json'

## Then you can use JSON
JSON.parse("{}")
```